# Simulated Kinect in gazebo with realistic error model

Tags: gazebo, simulation, kinect, simulator-gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has anyone extended the [gazebo_ros_openni_kinect](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/gazebo_plugins/html/gazebo__ros__openni__kinect_8cpp_source.html) plugin to deliver noisy data that is closer to reality than the current "perfect" point clouds the plugin provides? I know that adding this isn't too difficult, but I figured I might just ask if anyone else has already implemented this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27973/simulated-kinect-in-gazebo-with-realistic-error-model/) by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on ROS Answers with karma: 24361 on 2012-02-20

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [balakumar-s](https://answers.ros.org/users/5452/balakumar-s/) on 2015-08-15**:
Did you figure out a way to deliver noisy data in Gazebo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not for gazebo, but we did a kinect simulator in BlenSor that can export pointclouds in PCD (pointcloud libray data) format

[Here](http://www.blensor.org/node/51)
[and here](http://www.blensor.org/node/49)

regards
Michael

---

Originally posted by [mgschwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2669/mgschwan/) with karma: 36 on 2013-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0